# How to resolve DataAccessResourceFailureException in a Batch Job?

Tags: java, spring

I have a batch job which runs twice and once in a while I get `org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: StatementCallback`. I did some analysis and I found out that it is not a Database issue. This happens when JDBC is not able to connect to database. I don't see this exception everyday. I am not sure what else do I need to check?

I get the DB connection from the properties file using Spring JDBC template.

`jdbc.source.url=jdbc:sqlserver://dbServer:1433;DatabaseName=dbname
jdbc.source.username=userName
jdbc.source.password=pass!`

Stack trace:

```
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Connection reset
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:2400) ~[sqljdbc42.jar:?]
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:2384) ~[sqljdbc42.jar:?]
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.read(IOBuffer.java:1884) ~[sqljdbc42.jar:?]
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSReader.readPacket(IOBuffer.java:6642) ~[sqljdbc42.jar:?]
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSReader.nextPacket(IOBuffer.java:6595) ~[sqljdbc42.jar:?]
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSReader.ensurePayload(IOBuffer.java:6571) ~[sqljdbc42.jar:?]
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSReader.readBytes(IOBuffer.java:6864) ~[sqljdbc42.jar:?]
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSReader.readWrappedBytes(IOBuffer.java:6886) ~[sqljdbc42.jar:?]
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSReader.readInt(IOBuffer.java:6827) ~[sqljdbc42.jar:?]
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSReader.readUnsignedInt(IOBuffer.java:6844) ~[sqljdbc42.jar:?]
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.PLPInputStream.readBytesInternal(PLPInputStream.java:313) ~[sqljdbc42.jar:?]
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.PLPInputStream.getBytes(PLPInputStream.java:129) ~[sqljdbc42.jar:?]
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.DDC.convertStreamToObject(DDC.java:616) ~[sqljdbc42.jar:?]
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.ServerDTVImpl.getValue(dtv.java:4030) ~[sqljdbc42.jar:?]
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.DTV.getValue(dtv.java:226) ~[sqljdbc42.jar:?]
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.Column.getValue(Column.java:144) ~[sqljdbc42.jar:?]
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.getValue(SQLServerResultSet.java:2099) ~[sqljdbc42.jar:?]
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.getValue(SQLServerResultSet.java:2084) ~[sqljdbc42.jar:?]
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.getString(SQLServerResultSet.java:2441) ~[sqljdbc42.jar:?]
at com.mercuryinsurance.r3.migration.dao.DataMigrationDaoDailyImpl.lambda$16(DataMigrationDaoDailyImpl.java:329) ~[migration.jar:?]
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:93) ~[spring-jdbc-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:60) ~[spring-jdbc-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1QueryStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:455) ~[spring-jdbc-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:400) ~[spring-jdbc-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
```

Comment: Can you provide db connection config?

Comment: I get the DB connection from the properties file using Spring's JDBC template.

Comment: can you paste properties file?

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: Thank you, are other requests to db successful?

Comment: Yes, as I said this exception occurs once in two weeks. It doesn't happen everyday.

Comment: Facing the same issue, I am very well aware it happens for a particular request where the response is a heavier payload.